Does saltwater flooding cause permanent damage to electrical wiring?
Does saltwater flooding cause permanent damage to electrical wiring?  A category 5 hurricane will strike the west coast of Florida.  I am on the east coast near saltwater.
I'd like to leave the electric on when I evacuate tomorrow. However, if I turn it off, will it reduce the likelihood of damage to the electrical wiring if saltwater manages to infiltrate?

Another answer already reasonably answers the question of this particular storm.
However, in general I would consider the following:

Water can damage nearly everything in a house. There are reasons why houses that get flooded sometimes get torn down as the renovation costs can be higher than the rebuild costs. There are reasons why cars are often totaled due to flooding even if they dry out and seem to be mostly OK. So an actual high-water mark above any electrical equipment (and drywall and carpet and furniture and...) puts anything below that mark at serious concerns of being unsalvageable. That being said, if the damage is rain, waves, storms passing through but not actual flooding of a building, the concerns are much lower.
If electric devices are "on" then they can be damaged quite severely by even a little bit of water that gets in. Note that many appliances have electronic components that are "on" even when the primary functions are off. The classic example is the clock on a VCR - you aren't playing or recording a show but the VCR is still on.
If electric devices are "off", whether deliberately or due to a power outage, they are often perfectly fine once they dry out, as long as they weren't actually flooded for an extended period of time.
There are some devices where being "on" with some risk is better than being "off" and guaranteed useless. Classic examples are alarms (fire, smoke, burglar) and refrigeration equipment.

If you have no "really need to leave on" things such as refrigeration equipment (if you leave your refrigerator off and empty, open the door so it will be less likely to grow mold while you're gone) then the simple solution is to flip the main breaker on your way out. If that is not practical (e.g., refrigerator or freezer that, provided there isn't an extended outage, will keep a lot of expensive food from spoiling), turn off all the circuits you don't need at the breaker panel. Turning them off at the breaker panel works best for hardwired devices (e.g., oven, water heater, lights/fans) and is often easier than unplugging everything else.

For refrigeration equipment, the temperature change within depends on both how long the outage lasts and how "full" the piece of equipment is: the fuller, the more thermal inertia it's got. Packing a freezer with bottles of (cold) water ahead of time, and letting them freeze completely before pulling the plug, then keeping the lid shut, will allow for a 1 or 2 days outage without much risk. And it also makes checking easier: if the water is no longer frozen when you open the lid, then you can throw everything out, but as long as it is, you're good.

In the interest of shared information, one of the most knowledgeable and experienced meteorologists, Denis Philips, shares his expertise.
Cat 5 doesn't get to the west coast of Fla.  maybe a 3.
East coast of Fla is expected to have some tropical force winds, and the southern part of the storm is expected to be sheared off.
Further, the storm is very small. Nothing like the size of Helene. The strongest winds only go out about 5 miles.
So if you are on the East coast you will not be getting much, if any surge.
Back to the question: Water and electricity do not mix. Saltwater is very bad, if your electric is on or off. However, again, if you are on the east coast you should be fine. Where I am (West Coast,  Sarasota) People are leaving and going to the east coast.

Thank you and I hope you / family have fared well

Thanks for asking.  We are alive and well, but tired with a lot to clean up.
